# Vue.js Modal Dialog Input forms

Tags: vue.js, dialog

I'm looking for a best practice or even a rule of thumb.  I understand that an Input dialog form can be made into a component for re-usability. But if a popup dialog form is only going to be used on that one Vue.js page it can be embedded in the html of that page.

The question is at what point are there too many dialog forms on a page?  Does it make a difference if the external dialog are all imported anyway?

If I need 5-7 input dialog's to add name information, education information, home information etc and each form will only be associated to that vue page does it make a difference?  What about performance?

I know I will be pinged for asking this question but honestly I don't know where the best place would be.

I totally agree that this can be subjective but isn't that the purpose to get opinions?

Answer (score 0):

The general rule (DRY) is that if you use it more than once, you should make a component for it but this rule can be broken if it would harm the programs simplicity.

You should decide it yourself how you would like to implement it. At the end of the day it comes down to personal preference.